# Minor changes: Not bumping up an edited question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Like Wikipedia, is there a way here at stack exchange to sign an edit as 'minor' (like in grammar, spelling corrections) and avoid bumping the question to the top of the list?

---

**Suggestion:**

1. Having the feature *only* for the individual question owners. That way, if they find a minor mistake a bit late, they could correct it and if someone else finds a 'significant' mistake, they could tell them to correct it.

Comment: No, there isn't: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/feature-request-trivial-edit-checkbox

Comment: That suggests that the feature is... trivial. Well, 5 minutes and I'm *delting thas qustionne.*

Comment: This meta discussion has the objections laid out more clearly, IMHO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers

Answer (score 1):

This is a good idea, but, as Standback's and balpha's links have pointed out, Stack Exchange has clearly said no to this, because [they feel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26496/149375) it would make the site less transparent:

> Implementing any sort of "don't bump" functionality **would also delay accountability** and transparency for those edits.
>
> Notifying users of edits in the system allows them to take a look at the content and make sure there isn't something fishy going on. Imagine if people could make changes to the system without *anybody* noticing. **That is very exploitable.**

I understand their concerns, but don't entirely agree with SE's position. (I haven't pursued it because but the issue isn't *that* important to me.)

Can you think of a way to propose this that would counter SE's objections about transparency and accountability?

Comment: And by the way, it's most important to *me* about *me.* That is, when I'm correcting my own questions... Hey! Maybe that's it: How about having the feature for question 'openers' only? Where should I send this?

Comment: Steck Exchange will likely go for solutions that are useful to the greatest number of people without complicating the site, so your solution would have to be those. As to where, after thoroughly reading the existing thread (linked to in this answer), then post a new one that explicitly states how it's not the same. (If your suggestion is too similar to the old one, it'll get closed as a duplicate. Sometimes even if it's not *that* similar.) Don't lose heart if the suggestion is declined; getting SE to implement a new feature is very difficult. Good luck!